# Deploying simpleStorage contract with Kaleido

Tags: truffle, quorum, kaleido

I have been following this tutorial to connect the consortium i have created using the Kaleido UI to truffle: [link](http://console.kaleido.io/docs/docs/truffle/) .  When i finally do :  ./truffle_migrate.sh
 it gets stuck in there, here is the output:

> $ ./truffle_migrate.sh
>   + truffle migrate --network supnode --reset Using network 'supnode'.
>
> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js Saving artifacts... Running
>   migration: 2_deploy_simplestorage.js   Deploying SimpleStorage...
>   ... 0xd6d9cfe1ab5b01abb759fb8280920d8f7ba0cef73340af22e47a9c7e40120c14

I don't understand where is the problem, i'm sure i have followed the tutorial carefully and i ve created the same scenario.. If anyone have any idea i would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I went through step by step in an attempt to recreate your scenario - 3 nodes running Quorum + Raft and a private transaction between nodes 1 & 3.

On the initial migration attempt I came across the same hung state as you observed.  Inspection of the block explorer reveals that both contracts were actually deployed, however neither were invoked (i.e. no state was set for simple storage via the migration file).

I then changed the truffle_migrate.sh file to target the original privateFor node (3) and used the original targeted node (1) as the new privateFor recipient.  This worked immediately.  The question is why :)

Truffle is finicky sometimes, especially when using RAFT with private transactions.

I would suggest:

1. Check your block explorer to ensure that the connection to the network was successful and the contracts were deployed.
2. Kill the running migrate process and just kick it off again.
3. If that doesn't work, try the flip flop process I described.

I'm curious if there is a correlation with targeting the RAFT leader or if perhaps truffle just needs a few extra nudges sometimes.  We will investigate.

FYI I tried originally with a public transaction and used a truffle.js file with only a single node.  This also worked immediately.  So my supposition is there is some nuanced approach for private transactions and RAFT.

In the meantime this should give you a potential workaround; you'll just have the original migration and simple storage contracts as orphans in your environment.

Comment: I should also add that you don't necessarily need to run a second migration.  You can simply follow the `Contract Abstraction` section in the doc and invoke the already deployed contract.

Comment: First thank you so much for your reply, i have tried the process you described also i have tried sending a public transaction with one node like you said, unfortunately the terminal still shows the same output and still gets stuck however in the explorer it shows that the contract was created as you mentioned.

Comment: hmmmmm,, that was weird... after trying as i said your process and trying sending the private tx .. i now returned things to the very first process i tried ...and by a miracle ..it worked immediately... i dnt know why but it did XDD .. If ever you had any insights on why it did work i would really appreciate it if you tell me. Working with truffle and kaleido(Quorum+Raft) seems to be a bit of a hurdle ,, for now at least..